# Is there a way to delete once tracked files in my (remote) git repo, that are not present in my local version?

Tags: git

I've got a problem with my git repo...
(A lot of time ago?) I deleted some files within my git repo, and I'm not sure anymore what exactly I did: did I use "git rm ..." or didn't I?
Recently I've come to work on the project contained in the repo again, and the first thing I'd like to do is "tidy up" the repository.
However, the problem now is that `git status` shows me there are changes not staged for commit for example:

`deleted: exampleDir/exampleFile`

this file is not present in the local version of the git repo anymore and is one of those files I deleted a long time ago. And there are a lot of those. I tried to stage those changes for commit using different commands like:
`git add *
git add exampleDir/*
git rm exampleDir/exampleFile
git rm --cached exampleDir
git rm --cached -r exampleDir/*
git rm --cached -r exampleDir/\*`

Unfornutately none of those worked: the `git add` commands did nothing at all
while the `git rm` commands told me `fatal: pathspec 'exampleDir/exampleFile' did not match any files`

How can I safely delete those once-tracked and not present anyomore on my local repository files? Or, alternatively, tell git to use my current local repository for the remote one as well?
I hope this is not too hard to understand and would appreciate help greatly...

Comment: Commit the delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I deleted some files within my git repo

The problem seems to be that you *didn't* do that.

If `git status` says `deleted: exampleDir/exampleFile` as *not* staged for commit, that tells you that `exampleDir/exampleFile` is in the index, and git is noticing that it is not also in the *work tree.*

(That is, it is not present in the files that *you can see*. That is not the repo. It is just the files that you can see. The index isn't the repo either, if it comes to that. This file, in some form, most certainly *is* in the repo and will *always* be in the repo. That is what the repo is: a collection of all the snapshots [commits] you've ever made, forever.)

So:

1. Say `git rm --cached exampleDir/exampleFile` and git will remove this file from the index.
2. You will know that this worked, because when you say `git status` again, git will no longer mention this file.
3. After you've done that for all the files you want to remove from the index, `git commit` so that the next commit will not contain those files, just like the index (now) doesn't and your work tree doesn't, and everything will match up as you desire.

Comment: By the way, if you'd like to "see" the contents of the index at this moment, say `git ls-files`. You will see `exampleDir/exampleFile` among the files; if you did not, git would not be commenting on the discrepancy between the index and the work tree.

Comment: thanks, I wrote a python script to do this command for all of those files and it worked in an instant... Weird I think I tried this before and just did not see the outcome when checking `git status` again...